# Partition Theorem to show $P(W \gt Z)$

Tags: random-variables, integer-partitions, uniform-distribution, independence

I am confused as to how to use the partition theorem on the following example? Any help is appreciated!

Suppose that W has a U(0,1) distribution and suppose that W is independent of the random variables X and Y (and hence, is independent of the random variable Z = X + Y ). Use the Partition Theorem to determine $P(W \gt Z)$